# How to jointly use makeFeatSelWrapper and resample function in mlr

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection, mlr

I'm fitting classification models for binary issues using MLR package in R. For each model, I perform a cross-validation with embedded feature selection using "selectFeatures" function. In output, I retrieve mean AUCs over test sets and predictions. To do so, after having get some advices ([Get predictions on test sets in MLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222557/get-predictions-on-test-sets-in-mlr)), I use "makeFeatSelWrapper" function in combination with "resample" function. The goal seems to be achieved but results are strange. With a logistic regression as classifier, I get an AUC of 0.5 which means no variable selected. This result is unexpected as I get an AUC of 0.9824432 with this classifier using the method mentioned in the linked question.  With a neural network as classifier, I get an error message

> Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

What is wrong?

Here is the sample code:

```
# 1. Find a synthetic dataset for supervised learning (two classes)
###################################################################

install.packages("mlbench")
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)

# generate 1000 rows, 21 quantitative candidate predictors and 1 target variable 
p<-mlbench.waveform(1000) 

# convert list into dataframe
dataset<-as.data.frame(p)

# drop thrid class to get 2 classes
dataset2  = subset(dataset, classes != 3)

# 2. Perform cross validation with embedded feature selection using logistic regression
#######################################################################################  

library(BBmisc)
library(nnet)
library(mlr)

# Choice of data 
mCT <- makeClassifTask(data =dataset2, target = "classes")

# Choice of algorithm i.e. neural network
mL <- makeLearner("classif.logreg", predict.type = "prob")

# Choice of cross-validations for folds 

outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10,stratify = TRUE)

# Choice of feature selection method

ctrl = makeFeatSelControlSequential(method = "sffs", maxit = NA,alpha = 0.001)

# Choice of hold-out sampling between training and test within the fold

inner = makeResampleDesc("Holdout",stratify = TRUE)

lrn = makeFeatSelWrapper(mL, resampling = inner, control = ctrl)
r = resample(lrn, mCT, outer, extract = getFeatSelResult,measures = list(mlr::auc,mlr::acc,mlr::brier),models=TRUE)

# 3. Perform cross validation with embedded feature selection using neural network
##################################################################################

library(BBmisc)
library(nnet)
library(mlr)

# Choice of data 
mCT <- makeClassifTask(data =dataset2, target = "classes")

# Choice of algorithm i.e. neural network
mL <- makeLearner("classif.nnet", predict.type = "prob")

# Choice of cross-validations for folds 

outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10,stratify = TRUE)

# Choice of feature selection method

ctrl = makeFeatSelControlSequential(method = "sffs", maxit = NA,alpha = 0.001)

# Choice of sampling between training and test within the fold

inner = makeResampleDesc("Holdout",stratify = TRUE)

lrn = makeFeatSelWrapper(mL, resampling = inner, control = ctrl)
r = resample(lrn, mCT, outer, extract = getFeatSelResult,measures = list(mlr::auc,mlr::acc,mlr::brier),models=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your logistic regression part of the code a couple of times, you should also get the `Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument` error. However, I find it strange that fixing a particular seed (e.g., `set.seed(1)`) before resampling does not ensure that the error does or does not appear.

The error occurs in internal `mlr` code for printing the output of feature selection to the console. A very simple workaround is to simply avoid printing such output with `show.info = FALSE` in `makeFeatSelWrapper` (see code below). While this removes the error, it is possible that what caused it may have other consequences, although I it is possible the error only affects the printing code.

When running your code, I only get AUC above 0.90. Please find below a your code for logistic regression, slightly re-organized and with the workaround. I have added a droplevels() to the dataset2 to remove the missing level 3 from the factor, though this is not related with the workaround.

```
library(mlbench)
library(mlr)
data(BreastCancer)

p<-mlbench.waveform(1000)
dataset<-as.data.frame(p)
dataset2  = subset(dataset, classes != 3)
dataset2  <- droplevels(dataset2  )    

mCT <- makeClassifTask(data =dataset2, target = "classes")
ctrl = makeFeatSelControlSequential(method = "sffs", maxit = NA,alpha = 0.001)
mL <- makeLearner("classif.logreg", predict.type = "prob")
inner = makeResampleDesc("Holdout",stratify = TRUE)
lrn = makeFeatSelWrapper(mL, resampling = inner, control = ctrl, show.info = FALSE)
# uncomment this for the error to appear again. Might need to run the code a couple of times to see the error
# lrn = makeFeatSelWrapper(mL, resampling = inner, control = ctrl)
outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10,stratify = TRUE)
r = resample(lrn, mCT, outer, extract = getFeatSelResult,measures = list(mlr::auc,mlr::acc,mlr::brier),models=TRUE)
```

Edit: I've reported an [issue](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2485) and created a [pull request](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/pull/2486) with a fix.

Comment: Thank you. After further tests, it seems that it is linked to the use of sffs method.